Yes/No .An extension having Galois group of order $1$ is normal
Is the following statement true/false ?

An extension having Galois group of order $1$ is normal.

I  think this statement is false  take $K= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3}):\mathbb{Q}$
Galois$(K)=\{e\}$ because $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3})\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ but $K$ is not normal

Depends on your book's definition of Galois groups. Some require extensions to be Galois in order to have Galois groups. But in that case, this would be a silly problem to pose.

There are (boring) examples. Did you search the site?

@JyrkiLahtonen currently I cannot find the example

@Arthur Actually, I'm following Ian Stewart's Galois theory book. This is from exercise 11.7 (d) in Stewart's book.

As noted in the comments OP is following Ian Stewart's book, in which the definition of the Galois group of a field extension $E/F$, denoted $\Gamma(E/F)$, is given as the set of $F$-automorphisms of $E$.
Following that definition, yes, you simply need to find any extension of degree $n>1$ with trivial Galois group to act as a counterexample (as normal implies $|\Gamma(E/F)|=|E/F|$). Your example works as does for example $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.
